# Twitter API how to get the latest tweet | Python

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, twitter

I have these lines of code.just basically gets last 10-20 tweet from a person

```
import requests
import json    
bearer_token='******'
userid=******
#url='https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/{}'.format(username)
    
while True:
    count = count + 1
    url='https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{}/tweets'.format(userid)
    
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(bearer_token)}
    
        response= requests.request('GET',url,headers=headers)
        tweetsData=response.json()
        
        print(json.dumps(tweetsData,indent=4,sort_keys=True))
```

I want to have last one only how?
plz help me...

Comment: Can you include the complete output of the print statement in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the API documentation for this endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets), the `max_results` option can be applied:

> `max_results`

> Specifies the number of Tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of 100 per distinct request. By default, 10 results are returned if this parameter is not supplied. The minimum permitted value is 5. It is possible to receive less than the max_results per request throughout the pagination process.`

So, modifying your `url`, you can retrieve 5 Tweets as a minimum.

```py
    url='https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{}/tweets?max_results=5'.format(userid)
```

If you only want to process or display a single one, you will need to do something with the value of `tweetsData` in order to truncate it to only a single Tweet.

Comment: thank you is there way to get less than 5 tweet :-)

Comment: The API returns 5 Tweets as a minimum. You will have to discard 4 of them in your code.